# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OImPG.png)I'm using useEffect hook to use fetch api but it doesn't work. when there is only one api it is working fine but when i use another api to fetch data using the useEffect hook in the createData function it gives error.

I did some research and i think it is because of some issues caused in re rendering of component in react, i tried to search for the fix but couldn't find it so I'm posting it, if there is any question kindly ask me in comments I'll give more details about it.

```
export default function Unpaid({ transporterId, getFn }) {
  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState([]);
  const [resData, setResData] = useState([]);


  const idUrl =
    "https://url...";

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    fetch(idUrl)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setResData(data));

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  console.log(resData, "response data");

  const dispatchId = resData.map((item) => item.id);
  console.log(dispatchId, "dispatch id");

  function createData(
    po,
    id
  ) {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(
        "https://url+id"
      )
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((data) => setItemData(data));
    }, []);

    console.log(itemData, "yohohoho");

    return {
      po,
    };
  }

  function Row(props) {
    const { row } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    return (
     <>
       jsx content
     </>
    );
  }


  const rows = resData.map((item) =>
    createData(
      item.purchase_order_details.po_number &&
        item.purchase_order_details.po_number.length > 0
        ? item.purchase_order_details.po_number
        : "NA",
     
      item.id
    )
  );
 
  return (
   <>
     jsx content
   </>
  );
}
```

Comment: you're not closing your fetch endpoint here `"https://url+id`

Comment: i have changed the link, the link is fine, changed it for privacy

Comment: I meant you are missing `"` in the end

Comment: i edited it, but it isn't missing in my code so it is not the problem

Comment: Is it even normal to have components declared inside components ?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `createData` inside `resData.map(...)`, you are calling `useEffect` in a loop, which violates the [rules for hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). You can call hooks only on the top level.

To fix this, you should move the effect outside of `createData` to the top level, add the dependency `resData` to the and loop over resData inside the effect.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    fetch(idUrl)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setResData(data));

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  const dispatchId = resData.map((item) => item.id);

  useEffect(() => {
  function createData(
    po,
    id
  ) {

      fetch(
        "url" 
      )
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((data) => setItemData(data));
           return {
      po,
      
    };
  }
}, [resData]);

Comment: i did it like this but now it says createData is not defined